# resample data based on group and calculate rolling sum

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I would like to create an additional column in my data-frame without having to loop through the steps

```
This is created in the following steps.

 1.Start from end of the data.For each date resample every nth row 
 (in this case its 5th) from the end.
 2.Take the rolling sum of x numbers from 1 (x=2)

 a worked example for 
 11/22:5,7,3,2 (every 5th row being picked) but x=2 so 5+7=12
 11/15:6,5,2 (every 5th row being picked) but x=2 so 6+5=11


        cumulative 
 8/30/2019  2   
 9/6/2019   4   
 9/13/2019  1   
 9/20/2019  2   
 9/27/2019  3   5
 10/4/2019  3   7
 10/11/2019 5   6
 10/18/2019 5   7
 10/25/2019 7   10
 11/1/2019  4   7
 11/8/2019  9   14
 11/15/2019 6   11
 11/22/2019 5   12
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume we have a set of 15 integers:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15], columns=['original_data'])
```

We define which nth row should be added `n` and how many times `x` we add the `nth` row

```
n = 5
x = 2

(
    df

    # Add `x` columsn which are all shifted `n` rows
    .assign(**{
        'n{} x{}'.format(n, x): df['original_data'].shift(n*x)
        for x in range(1, reps)})

    # take the rowwise sum
    .sum(axis=1)
)
```

Output:

```
    original_data   n5 x1
0   1               NaN
1   2               NaN
2   3               NaN
3   4               NaN
4   5               NaN
5   6               1.0
6   7               2.0
7   8               3.0
8   9               4.0
9   10              5.0
10  11              6.0
11  12              7.0
12  13              8.0
13  14              9.0
14  15              10.0
```